# How exactly works Spring JUnit test that uses stubs?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts about how exactly works the **unit test** with **stubs**.

For example I have the following slide:

[image]

So I think that it means that in the **production environment** I have an **AuthenticatorImpl** class that use a **JpaAccountRepo** service\repository that is a **dependency** and it is 
itself related to some dependencies and to the prodution environment (Spring, configurations and the DB).

So if I want to test **AuthenticatorImpl** as a **unit** I have to **remove links to all dependencies**.

So using **stub** way I have to create a stub of the previous first dependency of the unit that I want to test. In this case it is **JpaAccountRepo** so I can create a generic **AccountRepoStub** that is a fake implementation that don't use a database and don't use a specific tecnology to access data (I am not testing **JpaAccountRepo** so I can use a fake implementation because it is a unit test and not an integration test).

Is it my reasoning right untill now?

So for example if this is my **AuthenticatorImpl** class

```
public class AuthenticatorImpl implements Authenticator {
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AuthenticatorImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        Account account = accountRepository.getAccount(username);
        return account.getPassword().equals(password);
    }
}
```

As you can see the constructor **AuthenticatorImpl()** constructor take a **AccountRepository** object as paramether (that is an interface and not an implementation).

So I can create my **stub** class named **StubAccountRepository** that implement **AccountRepository** interface

```
class StubAccountRepository implements AccountRepository {
    public Account getAccount(String user) {
        return “lisa”.equals(user) ? new Account(“lisa”, “secret”) : null;
    }
}
```

So finnally I can create my **unit test** implementing an **AuthenticatorImplTests** class

```
import org.junit.Before; import org.junit.Test; ...

public class AuthenticatorImplTests {
    private AuthenticatorImpl authenticator;

    @Before 
    public void setUp() {
        authenticator = new AuthenticatorImpl( new StubAccountRepository() );
    }

    @Test 
    public void successfulAuthentication() {
        assertTrue(authenticator.authenticate(“lisa”, “secret”));
    }

    @Test 
    public void invalidPassword() {
        assertFalse(authenticator.authenticate(“lisa”, “invalid”));
    }
}
```

So in my **setUp** method I build an **AuthenticatorImpl** object passing to it my stub **StubAccountRepository** so I removed the link with the dependency and I am testing only the **AuthenticatorImpl** unit.

Is it right or am I missing something?

Tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it.

Most of the time, you don't create a Stub class explicitely though, but use a mocking framework like [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) which creates it, dynamically, for you. For example:

```
AccountRepository stub = mock(AccountRepository.class);
authenticator = new AuthenticatorImpl(stub);

when(stub.getAccount("lisa")).thenReturn(new Account(“lisa”, “secret”));
```